# How call a variable from another file?

Tags: java, android

I want to call a variable from a class to another one (in my example, from WifiActivity to WifiBroadcastReceiver) . I use a method to to this, this is my code :

WifiActivity.java :

```
public class WifiActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    [...]

    public boolean getLocalizationState() {
        return localizationPhase; //localizationPhase is defined as boolean
    }

    [...]
}
```

WifiBroadcastReceiver.java :

```
public class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiActivity wifiActivity;  //
    [...]
    private boolean localizationState;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        [...]

        while(position<=numberdisplay-1){ // While we have not read all the AP RSSI average
            localizationState=wifiActivity.getLocalizationState(); //The problem is here!!!
            if(sampleposition[position]!=0  && localizationState==true){ 
                [...]
            }
            [...]
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

When I use `wifiActivity.getLocalizationState()` it returns 'false', but actually it is 'true' when I look in the debug mode : variables->context->localizationPhase='true'
I have the impress that `wifiActivity.getLocalizationState()` just read the definition of the variables, but not the changes. I have the same problem for other methods I call, it doesn't return the same thing that the debug window does.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Sorry for my English...

Edit : This is the begining of the WifiActivity class :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);
```

@Jason C : Do you think about this when you talk about initalization? Sorry for my lack of knowledge...

Comment: Did you set localizationPhase to static?

Comment: How do you initialize `wifiActivity`?

Comment: Where do you set `localizationPhase`? The thing is that this variable, being defined as `boolean` and **not** `Boolean` will be set to the default `false`, unlike the `Boolean` object, which is `null` by default. I don't know at what point do you set `localizationPhase`, but you're probably looking for the value before it's set.

Comment: @lukronos No, do not set that to static. It may "work" but for the wrong reasons. You need to show us how you initialize `wifiActivity`. It would also be helpful if you could write a completely self-contained tiny test program that shows this behavior. Also verify that you are actually observing the correct location in the debugger.

Comment: @lukronos First, you should put comments in the comments section of questions here so others will notice. It is only by chance that I noticed your comment in your post. Second, to answer you: No, where do you set the value of `wifiActivity`? Where is `wifiActivity = ...`?

Comment: Ok, I have just written : `wifiActivity = new WifiActivity();` (I forgot to paste it in the original post)

Answer (score 0):

You really never need to do anything like this when working with Android:

```
private WifiActivity wifiActivity;
```

Try using extras in your Intent to pass information between components instead.

Comment: What do you mean when you say extras? Can you give me an example if it is possible? I am sorry I am a beginner in coding :s

Comment: [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).  You should probably go look at the intent documentation on the android developer page and do some of the tutorials.

Comment: This is a good point but it also does not address the OPs question regarding the return value of `getLocalizationState()`, and is more appropriate as a comment on the question.

Comment: @JasonC Its still the root cause of his problem. The approach is completely wrong. The focus should be on re-doing it the right way versus trying to fix the current code.

Comment: @elevine An analysis of the problem at hand *combined* with your suggestion of better design would be a constructive response. As it stands it is the "root" for some arbitrary definition of "root" - as much as the "root" cause is the OP trying to write an application in the first place (if he did not, the problem would be solved). :)

Comment: @JasonC Agreed that the combo would be the best answer.  I was feeling a bit lazy today and didn't put the effort into being as thorough as possible :)